# Coding arrays in constraint JuMP

Tags: julia, julia-jump

Please consider the following image:

[image]

I know when I use `a:b` in `@constraint` it means an array from `a` to `b`. I need to code the arrays like {a_j,b_j} in `@constraint` of the mentioned code. Can you please help me to code that?

Comment: You need to provide more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Here is the JuMP documentation: https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/manual/constraints

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dependent Arrays in Constraints JuMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69489076/dependent-arrays-in-constraints-jump)

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are asking about a custom indice iteration over a single constraint. This can be done in JuMP as:

```
using JuMP, Cbc
m = Model(Cbc.Optimizer)
@variable(m,x[1:3,1:3]>=0)
@constraint(m, con[ (i,j) in [(1,2),(2,3),(3,3)] ], x[i,j] >= 5)
```

Let us have a look what we got:

```
julia> println(m)
Feasibility
Subject to
 con[(1, 2)] : x[1,2] >= 5.0
 con[(2, 3)] : x[2,3] >= 5.0
 con[(3, 3)] : x[3,3] >= 5.0
 x[1,1] >= 0.0
 x[2,1] >= 0.0
 x[3,1] >= 0.0
 x[1,2] >= 0.0
 x[2,2] >= 0.0
 x[3,2] >= 0.0
 x[1,3] >= 0.0
 x[2,3] >= 0.0
 x[3,3] >= 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

A key point to understand is that--unlike AMPL and GAMS--there is no specialized
syntax for constructing and managing sets in JuMP. Instead, you can use any
available Julia syntax and datastructures.

Examples:

```
using JuMP
N = 10
model = Model();
@variable(model, x[1:N]);
@constraint(model, [s=1:3], sum(x[j] for j in 1:N if mod(j, s) == 0) == 1)
```

```
using JuMP
N = 10
model = Model();
@variable(model, x[1:N]);
d = [Set([1, 2, 3]), Set([2, 4, 6])]
a = [Set([3, 4]), Set([5])]
J(s) = [j for j in 1:2 if s in union(d[j], a[j])]
@constraint(model, [s=1:2], sum(x[j] for j in J(s)) == 1)
```

Comment: I tried both codes. But they do not work in my case. d and a are both subsets of set S in the size of N. For example: (N=5, T=3, S=6), j=1:N, t=1:T, s=1:S. `d=[1,2,2,3,1]` (the elements of d are the first 3 digits of S and the size of d is N) and `a=[6,4,5,6,4]` (the elements of a are the 3 last digits of set S and the size of a is N). Now I want to code that the index s is starting from d and ending with a.  It is like this s[j=1]={1,6}, s[j=2]={2,4}, s[j=3]={2,5}, s[j=4]={3,6}, s[j=5}={1,4}